# Getting portlet scope prefix

Tags: portlet, websphere-7, websphere-portal

My port let application (JSR-168) consist 2 portlets. Every portlet have own Portlet Scope. For example when I print my session variables:

```
[15.01.14 9:57:51:728 YEKT] 000000f2 SystemOut     O javax.portlet.p.Z7_4PT0G7H2006770A072T1VN3047?ChannelListForm : form.ChannelListForm@4589069
[15.01.14 9:57:51:728 YEKT] 000000f2 SystemOut     O javax.portlet.p.Z7_4PT0G7H2006770A072T1VN30O1?KhlScheduleList : beans.list.KhlScheduleList@5ff9df2d
```

How can I get Portlet Scope prefix in my jsp or set this prefix in Portlet Preferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with JSR-168 portlets before but you can using the `<portlet:namespace>` JSP tag. That will get you a String that has the portlet ID (aka your portlet scope prefix) followed by an '_'.